# PHP foreach statement produces no output

Tags: php, foreach

the following produces no output, when really it should show a list including Milk, Cheese and Yoghurt. It is probably something really simple, I just can't see it.

```
 <?php 

 $FoodList=array();
 $newArray =array();
 echo "<p>";


 $Dairy= array(
    'a' => 'Milk',
    'b' => 'Cheese',
    'c' => 'Yoghurt',
 );
 $Fruit = array(
    'd' => 'Apples',
    'e' => 'Oranges',
    'f' => 'Grapefruit',
 );
 $GlutenFree = array(
    'g' => 'GF Cookies',
    'h' => 'GF Pancakes',
    'i' => 'GF Bread',
 );
 $Sweets = array(
    'j' => 'Musk Sticks',
    'k' => 'Caramels',
    'l' => 'Chocolate',
 );


 if ($_POST['running'] == 'yes')
 {
    $newArray = array_merge($FoodList, $Dairy);

    foreach ($newArray as $key => $value)
    {
       echo $value;
    }
 }


 echo "<p>";
 ?>
```

This may because the FoodList Array does not have anything in it, so I will look into that, but I have a strong feeling it is related to something else.

Comment: What is in `$newArray`?  Use `print_r( $newArray )` to see what's in it.

Comment: @AndyLester `$newArray` is an empty array. Also I've tried your code and it works perfectly. Maybe the `$_POST['running']` !== 'yes'?

Comment: Actually, your handler should contain `$Running=$_POST['Running'];` then you should be checking if it's `true` meaning if it has been checked `if ($_POST['Running'] == true)` and your input should be `<input type="checkbox" name="Running" />` so when it's checked, it will return `MilkCheeseYoghurt` and nothing if it isn't checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "bug" must be coming from the line, the array merge is fine:

```
 if ($_POST['running'] == 'yes')
```

Comment: The HTML page states: Running 
<input type="checkbox" name="Running" value="Yes" />

Comment: I have changed 'running' to 'Running' but it still produces no output

Comment: `'running'` !== `'Running'`

Comment: @AndrewSmith In the future, post all relevant code in your question. One of the most important factors (50%) are form elements which were not posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

foreach($Dairy as $key => $value)
{

echo $value;
}